# Ethminer Error: Dag generation failure: Invalid Argument

Tags: mining, ethminer, dag

I have been mining for a while now. I restarted my computer this evening and I have been receiving the error " DAG Generation Failure. Reason: Invalid argument" when running the same bat file I always do. I have not made any changes to my system.

Comment: which miner are you using

Comment: im using cpp-ethereum ethminer

Comment: I think you should open an issue on their github.

Comment: Try to update your miner